# can anyone help me to explain pyhton syntax

Tags: python

```
def print_formatted(number):
    # your code goes here
    padding = len(bin(number)[2:])
    
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        print(f"{i: >{padding}} {oct(i)[2:]: >{padding}} "
              f"{hex(i)[2:].upper(): >{padding}} {bin(i)[2:]: >{padding}}")
```

I'm trying to debug above code i know the output and working of the code but i couldn't understand is that what

": >"

doing in f string formatting

can anyone help me to explain ": > " this syntax

Comment: Which parts of the string formatting language have you looked at already?

Comment: > to denote right alignment and use the value of {padding} for the width of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used for padding:

```
print(f"{8:<3}")
  8  # note three spaces
# make them visible:
print(f"{8:.<3}")
..8
```

In the last example the `.` is used instead of spaces.

Comment: thanks really helped its like rjust func